# How to display output on textpane in java renjin?

Tags: java, renjin

I'm beginner in `java` and `renjin`.
I need my output result show in my `jtextpane`, How I can do that? I'm so tired.
If you know how to do it, please tell me.
thanks

```
RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
        // create a Renjin engine:
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();

    try {
        //engine.eval("RealData <- read.csv('E:/R Project/Original Data Cleaning Data Historis.csv', header = TRUE)");                    
        engine.eval("RealData <- read.csv('"+textPath.getText().replace('\\','/')+"', header = TRUE)");                    
        //engine.eval("print(RealData)");
        engine.eval("library(e1071)");
        //engine.eval("tune.out <- tune(svm, hasil~., data=RealData, kernel=\"radial\",ranges = list(cost = c(1:10),gamma = c (1:4)))");
        //engine.eval("summary(tune.out)");
        engine.eval("svmfit <- svm(hasil~., data=RealData, kernel=\"radial\", cost=2, gamma=4)");

        editorSvm.setText(engine.eval("print(svmfit)").toString());


    } catch (ScriptException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Klasifikasi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }`
```

Answer (score 2):

The [print.svm](https://github.com/cran/e1071/blob/master/R/svm.R#L521) function always returns NULL, so you won't be able to get what you want by looking at the return value of `print()`.

Instead, the `print()` function will write the text to the ScriptEngine's standard output stream, which is by default sent to the process' standard output stream.

As now described in the [documentation][2], you can redirect the output from R to a StringWriter this way:

```
StringWriter outputWriter = new StringWriter();   
engine.getContext().setWriter(outputWriter);
engine.eval("print(svmfit)");

String output = outputWriter.toString();

// Reset output to console
engine.getContext().setWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

The output of the print.svm function will now be stored in the Java `output` variable.